# Creating my Own Twitter Bootstrap button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a web app using twitter bootstrap, i want to create my own button with my own background, i don't want to use the already present buttons using `btn-primary` etc... but i want to create my own button with my own class. I want to use the core functionality of the `btn` class. so ideally my button will use the `class=" btn btn-myPrimary"`.

I checked in variables.less and buttons.less, there only i am able to change the value of existing buttons such as `btn-primary`. i am not able create my own button something like `btn-myPrimary`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using?

Answer (score 7):

If you can compile the less files then you can use this button mixin (from [mixins.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L451)):

```
// Button variants
// -------------------------
// Easily pump out default styles, as well as :hover, :focus, :active,
// and disabled options for all buttons
.button-variant(@color; @background; @border) {
color: @color;
background-color: @background;
border-color: @border;
...
```

If you look at [buttons.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/buttons.less#L52) you can see how they use it:

```
.btn-default {
  .button-variant(@btn-default-color; @btn-default-bg; @btn-default-border);
}
.btn-primary {
  .button-variant(@btn-primary-color; @btn-primary-bg; @btn-primary-border);
}
// Warning appears as orange
.btn-warning {
  .button-variant(@btn-warning-color; @btn-warning-bg; @btn-warning-border);
}
// Danger and error appear as red
.btn-danger {
  .button-variant(@btn-danger-color; @btn-danger-bg; @btn-danger-border);
}
// Success appears as green
.btn-success {
  .button-variant(@btn-success-color; @btn-success-bg; @btn-success-border);
}
// Info appears as blue-green
.btn-info {
  .button-variant(@btn-info-color; @btn-info-bg; @btn-info-border);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this `ref links` below

**[Link](http://www.plugolabs.com/twitter-bootstrap-button-generator-with-awesome-font/)**